# Excel VBA: Update Pivot Sourcedata

Tags: database, vba, excel, pivot

I tried to record the code to update a pivot sourcedata which gave me this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlExternal, _
    SourceData:=QueryArry1, _
    Connection:=Array( _
        Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & DBDir & "\" & DBName & ";"), _
        Array("DefaultDir=" & DBDir & ";DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;") _
    )
```

But this doesn't even allow me to specify WHICH pivot table I want to update... or even do what I really want to do which is update the pivotcache so that all pivot tables using that same source are updated.

So what is a good way to update the sourcedata?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

But I even get the "application-defined or object-defined error" error with something as simple as:

```
str = Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.CommandText
Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.CommandText = str
```

And I did double check that my pivot table is still hitting the live data and refreshing it still works... yet I can't set the command string to what it is currently? So bizarre.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PivotCaches are accessible through Workbooks. You can list all your current caches with the following sub:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub listCaches()
    Dim selectedCache As PivotCache

    For Each selectedCache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
        Debug.Print selectedCache.Index
        Debug.Print selectedCache.Connection
    Next selectedCache

End Sub
```

You can access the connection you want to edit with:

```
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(yourIndex).Connection
```

Note: After changing the Connection you should call:

```
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(yourIndex).Refresh
```

**Edit:** Instead of changing the SourceData you can change the CommandText. That should have the same effect. The following code worked for me:

```
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).CommandText = "SELECT movies.title, movies.rating, movies.comments FROM `C:\Folder\moviesDB`.movies movies"
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Refresh
```

This code also updated my SourceData.

**Edit2:** Changing CommandText throgh PivotTable:

```
Sheets("mySheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.CommandText = "SELECT movies.title as meh, movies.rating, movies.comments FROM `C:\Folder\moviesDB`.movies movies"
Sheets("mySheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Note: moviesDB is a .mdb file and movies is the table/query

Note2: It might also help you to `Debug.Print` the working CommandText before changing it. This should give you a template for your new CommandText.

Comment: The Connection is fine, I'm trying to change the SourceData... but I get "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I try to "ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(2).SourceData = QueryArry1"... I'm starting to think that this type of SourceData reference is read-only and can't be used to set the value. I've tried several different forms of QueryArry1, including "QueryArry1=ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(2).SourceData"... I always get the same error

Comment: I am not sure what the contents of your QueryArry are but I guess you want to change the Query that is send to the database. Changing CommandText worked for me. I added a sample code in my answer.

Comment: The Pivot caches keep changing their index... So I'm trying the command: "Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Totals"" but it gives me the error: "application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: I was able to change CommandText thorgh PivotTable with the code I added in my answer. I was also able to replicate your Error by trying to set CommandText to a wrong Query like "SEEELEKT * From ..." or by not including the path to the database in the Query.

Comment: Still have unexplainable issues... see my edit. thanks for your work so far... hopefully I am almost there.

Comment: I renamed a sheet in Totals and added 2 PivotTables in it and executed the code from your edit with no problems. But I had to change str to bla because str is a Excel Function.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  While it still isn't working, you've really helped me refine my issue and approach.  I've made a new thread addressing the specific error I'm getting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883440/excel-vba-application-defined-or-object-defined-error