# Excel VBA: "application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: database, excel, vba, runtime, pivot

In Excel 2003 I'm getting a Runtime error 1004: "application-defined or object-defined error" on the last line of this code (commandtext = abc)

```
Sub SCommandTxt()
Dim abc as string
abc = Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.CommandText 
Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.CommandText = abc
End Sub
```

This isn't really what I'm trying to do, but not knowing what is causing an error in something as simple as this is driving me up a wall.  The Pivot table at hand is an ODBC connection.  The following code was run before this code and works fine.  All I really want to do is change the query dynamically based on the changing range "WhereFilters".  The below query works alright, but I'd prefer not to have to unhide and select the sheet and go through the pivotwizard if I can just change the commandText directly (though based on the errors I'm getting maybe not... Though others seem to think the above is possible, so I don't know why it isn't working for me):

```
Sub UpdatePvt()
Dim DBDir As String, DBName As String, SortType As String, Size As String
Dim QueryArry1(0 To 100) As String, rng As Range, x As Integer

DBDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\jt\"
DBName = "DatabaseExample.mdb"

If Range("ComboResult1") = 1 Then
    SortType = "TDollars"
    Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIV_ID").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Dollars"
    Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("DIV_ID").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Dollars"
Else
    SortType = "TCounts"
    Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIV_ID").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Counts"
    Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("DIV_ID").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Counts"
End If

If Range("ComboResult2") = 1 Then
    Size = "Total"
ElseIf Range("ComboParOUT") = 2 Then
    Size = "Small"
Else
    Size = "Large"
End If

QueryArry1(0) = "SELECT Top 500 C.* "
QueryArry1(1) = "FROM Final03 C "
x = 2
If Not (Range("NoFilters")) Then
    QueryArry1(x) = "INNER JOIN (Select DIV_ID FROM FullLookup WHERE "
    x = x + 1

    For Each rng In Range("WhereFilters")
        QueryArry1(x) = rng.Value
        x = x + 1
    Next rng

    QueryArry1(x) = "GROUP BY DIV_ID) E ON C.DIV_ID = E.DIV_ID "
    x = x + 1
End If
QueryArry1(x) = "WHERE C.EntitySize = '" & Size & "' "
QueryArry1(x + 1) = "ORDER BY C." & SortType & " DESC "

'Example Query Results:
'SELECT Top 500 C.* FROM Final03 C INNER JOIN (Select DIV_ID FROM FullLookup WHERE Year = 2008 and State = 'MN' and Type = 'RST44' GROUP BY DIV_ID) E ON C.DIV_ID = E.DIV_ID WHERE C.EntitySize = 'Large' ORDER BY C.TCounts DESC 

Sheets("Totals").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Sheets("Totals").Select
Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange.Select
Sheets("Totals").PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlExternal, _
    SourceData:=QueryArry1, _
    Connection:=Array( _
        Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & DBDir & "\" & DBName & ";"), _
        Array("DefaultDir=" & DBDir & ";DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;") _
    )

Sheets("Totals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataBodyRange.Select
Sheets("Totals").PivotTableWizard _
    SourceType:=xlPivotTable, _
    SourceData:="PivotTable1"

Sheets("Totals").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you comment on what the solution turned out to be?

Comment: The solution is the long code at the bottom of my post with unhiding sheets and selecting pivottables... I was hoping to do it directly with the Pivotcache, but still have not yet discovered a way.  Your answer was a great candidate and what I thought was going on at first, but didn't solve my issue.  Thanks for taking the time to try and answer my question.

Comment: You're welcome...but you really shouldn't mark my answer as accepted if it didn't solve the problem.  It's better to post your own answer and mark it as accepted.  No one gets any rep points that way, but it can help people who are researching a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the exact one described here:

[Limitation of PivotCache.CommandText property](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1003719.php)

How long is the string you're trying to set as CommandText?

Comment: I've tried shorter strings (simple select query <50 characters) and still get that error.  I just tried the SplitString function, but also still get the error. I double checked that CommandType = xlCmdSql (which happens to be 2).  So I'm really at a loss... You can see why I'm frusterated.